# Mongo GeoJSON: location object expected

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, database

I am trying to do a simple insert operation of a GeoJSON object into a Mongo database:

```
> db.users.ensureIndex({'loc': '2d'})
> db.users.insert({'loc': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [50, 50]}})
location object expected, location array not in correct format
```

There is no outside context - this is a fresh database and a fresh collection within the mongo shell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using?  I beleive GeoJSON is in 2.4+ In 2.2 you might need to do db.users.insert({'loc': [50.0, 50.0]})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/

says you should use 2dsphere to use GeoJSON

```
db.users.ensureIndex({'loc': '2dsphere'})
```

you used the old method

```
db.users.ensureIndex({'loc': '2d'})
```

you have to use

```
db.users.insert({'loc': [50.0, 50.0]})
```

Comment: Isn't the correct usage for a GeoJSON object more like `{'loc': {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      51.883582055556,
      -176.64247991667
    ]
  }